# Understanding a certain solution , if $(a_n)$ is a strictly decreasing sequence then $(a_n)$ is positive

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $(a_n)$ be a zero sequence ,if $(a_n)$ is a strictly  decreasing sequence then $(a_n)$ is positive

---

This is the solution in the textbook :

Given $(a_n)$ is a strictly decreasing sequence ( $a_n > a_{n+1}$ for all $n$) and zero sequence. we will prove that the elements are positive by contradiction.

Assume that there exists an $m \in \Bbb N$ such that $a_m \leq 0$ , since $a_{m+1} < a_m$ we get $a_{m+1} < 0$
and also $a_{m+2} < a_{m+1}$ and $a_{m+3} < a_{m+2} < a_{m+1}$

**from here we get that for all $n \geq m+2$ (this is what I did not understand) we have $a_n < a_{m+1}$
therefore almost for all $n$ $a_n \leq a_{m+1}$**

according to given information and knowing that if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent sequences and $a_n \leq b_n$ for all $n$ then $\lim_{ n \to \infty}a_n \leq \lim_{ n \to \infty}b_n $

putting that we get $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \leq a_{m+1}$ also $\lim_{ n \to \infty}a_n<0$ but according to given information $\lim_{ n \to \infty}a_n=0$ so we get a contradiction when we assume that there exists an element $a_m \leq 0$ therefore $a_n$ is positive

The solution is pretty understandable and simple but I could not understand the part in bold how did they get to that , where does it come from?

Thank you and hope my translation are understandable

Comment: Prove by induction that $a_{m+k+1}<a_{m+1}$ for all positive integers $k$. Then show that any integer $n \geq m+2$ can be written as $m+k+1$ for some positive integer $k$.

Comment: $(a_n)$ is strictly decreasing then all $a_k$ starting from $k=m+2$ will be less than $a_{m+1}$. $a_{m+1}>a_{m+2}>a_{m+3}>\ldots > a_{k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to know is :

If there exist $ N\in \Bbb N $ such that

$$(\forall n\ge N)\; a_n<b_n$$

then
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n\le \lim_{n\to+\infty}b_n$$
The limits could be real or infinite.

So, in your case, $ N=m+1 $ and

$$(\forall n\ge m+1)\; a_n\le a_{m+1}$$

So
$$\lim a_n\le a_{m+1}<a_m\le 0$$
thus
$$\lim a_n\ne 0$$

Comment: Thank you ! just why exactly $m+2$ in my case? wouldn't $m+1$ work the same?

Comment: @Adamrk Yes, you are right. I edited with $ m+1$. This proves you understood.